# Is this the best way to achieve Outook 2007+/windows 10/all e-mail clients HTML mail RWD breakpoints column effect?

Tags: html, email, outlook, breakpoints, vml

I haven't found in the Internet any solution to make a RWD (Responsive Web Design) breakpoints columns for html emails where after braking two columns next to each other into two centered one under the other when a screen has small width, so using information found elsewhere i had to try to figure out how to do something working best. Below is the code which work for the really old e-mail clients and Outlook 2007+ and windows 10 e-mail client - the rest can be done using styles and media query. The breakpoint. Of course for outlook 2007+ a column is going to always have fixed width, but the columns break down when screen width is about less than 600 px.
Is this the best solution available? My goal is basically not to ask this question but to share solution to the public. But i am going to ask a question in another topic about vertical alignment of below example when the columns have different heights (**yes the code below is lacking one little thing yet: columns are aligned in Outlook 2007+ to the bottom, not the top of the line**). Two columns with pictures example next to each other (basically just paste, please, your > 600px html e-mail and send to yourself):

```
<!--[if (gte mso 12)|(IE 8)|(IE 9)]><v:rect mso-position-vertical="top" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" stroked="false" inset="0,0,0,0" style="display:inline-block;width:270px;margin:0;padding;0;mso-position-vertical:top"><v:textbox xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" inset="0,0,0,0" style="mso-fit-shape-to-text: true"><![endif]-->

            <div class="rwd_width_100_percent_small_screen" style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:270px;">         
                <table class="rwd_width_100_percent_small_screen" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="270" border="0"  style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0px;">
                    <tr>
                     <td width="20"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="20" border="0"  style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0px;"><tr><td></td></tr></table></td>
                     <td valign="top" align="center" width="0%"><!--[if gte mso 12]><p style="display: none;">&nbsp;</p><![endif]--><p style="margin-top: 6px;"><img src="images/describing_image.jpg" alt="" /></p></td><td width="100%" valign="top">
                        <p align="justify" style="margin-top: 10px;line-height:12px;text-align:justify"><font size="1" color="#005a96" face="Verdana,sans-serif" style="font-size: 10px;line-height:12px;">Some tekst next to a describing image</font></p>
                     </td>
                     <td width="20"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="20" border="0"  style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0px;"><tr><td></td></tr></table></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

      <!--[if (gte mso 12)|(IE 8)|(IE 9)]></v:textbox></v:rect><![endif]-->          


<!--[if (gte mso 12)|(IE 8)|(IE 9)]><v:rect mso-position-vertical="top" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" stroked="false" inset="0,0,0,0" style="display:inline-block;width:270px;margin:0;padding;0;mso-position-vertical:top"><v:textbox xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" inset="0,0,0,0" style="mso-fit-shape-to-text: true"><![endif]-->

            <div class="rwd_width_100_percent_small_screen" style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:270px;">         
                <table class="rwd_width_100_percent_small_screen" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="270" border="0"  style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0px;">
                    <tr>
                     <td width="20"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="20" border="0"  style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0px;"><tr><td></td></tr></table></td>
                     <td valign="top" align="center" width="0%"><!--[if gte mso 12]><p style="display: none;">&nbsp;</p><![endif]--><p style="margin-top: 6px;"><img src="images/describing_image.jpg" alt="" /></p></td><td width="100%" valign="top">
                        <p align="justify" style="margin-top: 10px;line-height:12px;text-align:justify"><font size="1" color="#005a96" face="Verdana,sans-serif" style="font-size: 10px;line-height:12px;">Some tekst next to a describing image</font></p>
                     </td>
                     <td width="20"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="20" border="0"  style="padding:0;border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0px;"><tr><td></td></tr></table></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

      <!--[if (gte mso 12)|(IE 8)|(IE 9)]></v:textbox></v:rect><![endif]-->
```

Of course - you can use table align="left" two get two tables next to each other but after brakipoint they are one under another but aligned left not center - so what is above work the best right now for me. **Let me remind the question. Is the above example the best RWD solution for html e-mails?**

Comment: What do you mean by "a RWD breaking point"?

Comment: I mean a breakpoint :) When there are for example two columns in a html layout, next to each other, when you narrow the screen width or on your desktop web browser you lessen the width of you browser window at some point when the width is less than f.e 600 px the two columns in line change in to one in line one under another. Thing commonly known in bootstrap framework and there is a phrase used, breakpoint. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/  I'll correct it. Sorry.

Comment: I know about the term "breakpoint", but I have no clue about that RWD stuff - does it mean "read, write, delete"?

Comment: It stand for Responsive Web Design.